# Horizontal bars using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, progress-bar, visualization, percentage

I am new to Python and I wanted to know if there was any way, using a library, to display such [bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BReFk.png). Not necessarily with the colors or the percentage shown, but this idea of horizontal bars showing a level of progress.

I've tried the barh tool of matplotlib but it doesn't seem to be what I need, since I can only have a horizontal bar going to a certain value, but not the "empty" part (let's say if I have 60%, "empty" part would be the other 40%), plus it lacks of customization (hide the graph axis etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see this as being a duplicate of that question.

I don't know of a way to natively do this, but you can always plot two bars to get the effect.

Hmm, I tried to put code here, but I guess you can't in comments.

Comment: Yeah it is a shame, it only answers a part of my question but not the main part... But thanks I think I understand what you mean, I would have loved an example of this but unfortunately... :/

Comment: Ernest has given you all the information you need. 1) Plot your values with [ax.barh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html) `ax.barh(categories, percentages, height = 0.6)` 2) Plot your 100% empty hull on top `ax.barh(categories, 100, height = 0.6, edgecolor = "black", linewidth = 5, fill = False)` 3) Remove axes etc. `plt.axis('off')` Done.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me there!